# Why is my nested function not called from my anonymous function?

Tags: php, anonymous-function, nested-function

I tried accomplishing a small task in PHP 7.4 (a language I never use) and decided to use a nested utility function `isReverseScored`, to be called inside an "arrow function", like so:

```
    // this is all inside a normal function, i.e. this is nested:
    function isReverseScored($questionIndex) { return in_array($questionIndex, $reverseScoredIndices); }

    $scores = array_map(
        fn ($value, $index) => isReverseScored($index) ? 8 - $value : $value,
        $values,
        array_keys($values));
```

`array_map` is called 18 times, but `isReverseScored` is never called. Why not?

The anonymous function always seems to evaluate to `$value`. Replacing the call with the actual body of `isReverseScored` gives the expected results:

```
        fn ($value, $index) => in_array($index, $reverseScoredIndices) ? 8 - $value : $value,
```

I declare another nested function (`arithmeticMean`) right next to the first one, which I can call just fine, albeit I'm not calling that one from within an anonymous function.

All of the above leads me to believe that I've declared the nested function correctly and called it in a valid position. I used a nested function because it appeared to be an available feature.

Comment: `isReverseScored` knows __nothing__ about `$reverseScoredIndices`

Comment: @u_mulder If I understand correctly you're saying that I'm referencing local variables from what is technically another top level function? That's true... Yes, I walked right into that one.